# Grunt-style templates in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

I'm moving from Grunt to Gulp, and I used to use templates in my Grunfile.js to configure my tasks, as described [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)

templates in Grunt look like this one:

```
<%= blahblah.static %>
<%= blahblah.build %>
```

and I can't find any useful doc on how to achieve the same thing with Gulp...

Comment: Why not just use normal js? `var s = 'something' + variable + 'here'`. Grunt uses templates because you can't refer to other variables in the config when you define it in `initConfig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some complex strings to construct, you can always use underscore templates:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var tmpl = _.template('var 1: <%= var1 %>, var 2: <%= var2 %>, etc...');

//...

tmpl({var1: 'hello', var2: 'world'});
```

Otherwise, just use normal js string concatenation.